# What is the most simple way to test endpoint definition and required params

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, resteasy

I have the following `javax.ws.rs` endpoint interface.

```
@POST
@Path("{id}")
Response save(
        @PathParam("id") @NotNull String id,
        @HeaderParam("header") @NotNull String header,
        @NotNull @Valid SomeFancyBody body);
```

Now I need a unit test that checks that pathparam, header and body are marked as `NotNull` / `Valid`.

I dont like to mock the endpoint or generate it in my unit tests and call this endpoint with wrong data. I trust the library that implements the ws.rs api (RestEasy) and I am sure that if I define this correctly `@NotNull` and `@Valid` will do its job.

So does anyone have any idea how to test this elegantly and easily?

Edit: Runtime - Java 8, Wildfly

Comment: so you want to unit test, for example, when `id` is passed as null?

Comment: I want to test that id is marked as required / Notnull

Comment: What is your runtime container? Or have you looked at Arquillian?

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins I am looking for way to do this without test container like arquillian. But I am afraid that is not possible.

Comment: You either need a container or a mock container to really test it. You could use a standalone container like a `VertxJaxrsServer` or the `NettyJaxrsServer`. These are part of RESTEasy.